# Departing before the visa is valid, and landing when it is valid - is this a problem?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, china, vietnam

On August 31, I am flying out of Washington, DC to Ho Chi Minh City, with a connection in Beijing (both via Air China).  My connection will occur on September 1st, and by the time I arrive in Vietnam, it will then be September 2nd.

I do have a visa for Vietnam, but it becomes valid on September 1.  Will this be a problem when boarding my first leg on August 31 in Washington, DC?  I wouldn't think it should as my visa will be valid when I actually arrive in Vietnam.  Also, by the time I check in on August 31, it will already be September 1st in Vietnam (due to the 11 hour time difference). I also have a valid Chinese visa.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you will be fine, you will arrive with a valid visa.

The airline have a responsibility to ensure you will be allowed to *enter* the country, they will be checking that your visa will be valid and accepted in Vietnam *upon arrival*. When you arrive the border control will be checking that your visa is valid from that date, which it is.